# How do I transfer a redstone signal downwards on Minecraft Bedrock edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Im making an elevator and I need to click a button which will light a redstone line except the button is about 15 block above the redstone line, how can I get it to bring the pulse down to the redstone on bedrock?

Answer (score 1):

You can make an observer elevator, but the by far simplest way is to just make a 2x2 tower that goes down 1 right 1, down 1 right 1 in a circle and just drags redstone down it like redstone normally works.

Comment: Thanks! I just used repeaters to extend the pulse.

Answer (score 0):

Glass towers in Minecraft: Bedrock Editon can go downward, but if you use a slab tower, then it acts like glass and slabs do in the Java Edition.